Streamlit authenticator double click error
I am getting a strange error when using the authenticator. It works but when I enter a username and password, it doesn’t redirect to the next page unless I click the “Login” button twice. It worked previously and this issue only recently cropped up. Anyone know what might be causing this?
For reference, I’m basically using the standard authenticator code template
if st.session_state["authentication_status"]:
    authenticator.logout('Logout', 'main')
    st.write(f'Welcome *{st.session_state["name"]}*')
    #switch to new page here
elif st.session_state["authentication_status"] == False:
    st.error('Username/password is incorrect')
elif st.session_state["authentication_status"] == None:
    st.warning('Please enter your username and password')

